# I have a crash. Why does my class receive the notification?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

In the AViewController I do next thing.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[[AppDelegate delegate].tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

AViewController will be deallocated and BViewController will be appeared(it is first tab).

I have a crash.

1) AViewController calles dealloc

2) BViewController sends notification

3) I get crash in onRotation method of AViewController

Why does AViewController receive ntf_onRotation notification? I added removeObserver methods.

My classes

```
@implementation AViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(onRotation:)
                                             name:@"ntf_onRotation"
                                           object:nil];
}

-(void) viewDidUnload
{
 [super viewDidUnload];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"ntf_onRotation" object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"ntf_onRotation" object:nil];
[super dealloc];
}

@end

 @implementation BViewController

 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ntf_onRotation" object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
   {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ntf_onRotation" object:nil];
}
@end
```

Comment: Did you check all another references to AViewController? If AViewController still receive notifications then it means that AViewController is live.

Comment: I added NSLog to dealloc. I saw that it was called. It means that retain count of AViewController is equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

This should remove all observers including any unknown ones:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```